# awk and or sed command to sum the value in repeating tags in a XML

Tags: xml, shell, unix, aix

I have a XML in which `<Amt Ccy="EUR">3.1</Amt Ccy="EUR">` tag repeats.
This  (Ccy may vary) is under another  tag `<Main>`.
I need to sum all the values of `<Amt Ccy="EUR">` (Ccy may vary) coming only under `<Main>` using awk and or sed  command.

can some help?

Sample looks like below

```
<root>
    <Main>
            <someothertag>..</someothertag>
        <Amt Ccy="EUR">3.1</Amt>
    </Main>
                .
                .
                .
                some other tags
    <Main>
          <someothertag>..</someothertag>
             <Amt Ccy="SGD">51</Amt>
    </Main>
    <another>
      <Amt Ccy="EUR">10</Amt>
     </another>
</root>
```

Comment: what've you tried? and why don't you put an example of the file?

Comment: You might want to consider [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the following data

```
$ cat data.xml
<root>
    <Main>
            <someothertag>..</someothertag>
        <Amt Ccy="EUR">3.1</Amt>
    </Main>
    <Main>
          <someothertag>..</someothertag>
             <Amt Ccy="SGD">51</Amt>
    </Main>
    <another>
      <Amt Ccy="EUR">10</Amt>
     </another>
</root>
```

The following

```
$ echo "cat ///Amt[@Ccy='EUR']/text()" | xmllint --shell data.xml | awk '{s+=$1} END{print s}'
13.1
```

Uses the xmllint command to parse out the values of the Euro "Amt" XML tags, using an Xpath expression. The resultset is then summed by awk.

Using Xpath is the more native way to process XML.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few inconsistencies between your description and the sample file provided, as well as a few technical errors in your xml file. Here's what I think you're looking for using `awk`:

```
awk '/<Main>/ { f=1 } f && /Amt/ { split($0,a,/[<>]/); s+=a[3] } /<\/Main>/ { f=0 } END { print "The sum is:", s }' file
```

Results

```
The sum is: 54.1
```

Please note that the regex that I've used may require tweaking depending on your input. If there are cases where the above script fails, please consider [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/14041183/edit) your question with more sample data and expected output. We will then be able to help you further. Also, as per the comments, you may want to consider using a proper xml parser for this job.

---

***EDIT:***

From the comments below, the following should calculate the sums of the different currencies, which must be within `<Main>` and `</Main>` tags.

```
awk '/<Main>/ { f=1 } f && /<Amt.*Amt>/ { split($0,a,/[<>"]/); b[a[3]]+=a[5] } /<\/Main>/ { f=0 } END { for (i in b) printf "The sum of %s is: %s\n", i, b[i] | "sort" }' file
```

Results:

```
The sum of EUR is: 3.1
The sum of SGD is: 51
```

Comment: @user1929905: I think my answer should still suffice. Please let me know if I can help further.

Comment: Hi steve , i have edited the input xml further.few other tags are also coming inside <Main>.Can you please help

Comment: Also if i want to add currency wise total how to do?

Comment: @user1929905: I've updated the answer, I think it should do what you want. Please let me know how it goes. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "cat /root//Amt" |                            \
    xmllint --shell input.xml |                    \
    sed -n '/EUR/{s/[^>]*> *\([0-9.]*\).*/\1/p}' | \
    awk '{sum+=$1} END{print sum;}'
```

Comment: hi,I am getting as   xmllint:  not found.  sed: 0602-404 Function /EUR/{s/[^>]*> *\([0-9.]*\).*/\1/p} cannot be parsed.

Comment: Yes, this uses xmllint to parse the xml file. You need to install it otherwise you cannot use this answer

Comment: Apologies, just realised you have provided a similar answer to mine. +1

Comment: You have a small problem. The xpath expression "/root/Main/Amt" will not pick up the second Euro tag: "/root/another/Amt"

Answer (score 1):

Maybe someone will find following method usefull.

There's xpath **sum()** function that could be used to avoid using tools other than xmllint to sum up result:

```
echo "xpath sum(///Amt[@Ccy='EUR'])"|xmllint --shell data.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when needing to seach XML files, it is better to use an XML parser.

But if you file is simple enough, and only contains a single `<Amt Ccy="EUR">...</Amt>` per line and nothing else:

```
awk -F "[<>]" '$0 ~ "^[ \t]*<Amt Ccy=\"EUR\">.*</Amt>" { sum += $3}
               END { print sum }' your_file
```

What I am doing is

- selecting only lines beginning by 0 or more spaces/tabs and matching your specific tags,
- using `<` and `>` as field delimiters, your amount is field number 3,
- summing the amount in all selected lines,
- print the sum at the end of the script.

Comment: Hi jfgagne,I have edited the input xml further.can you please give the modified awk command.

Comment: Your input does not meet the 'simple enough' criteria anymore.  You now need an XML parser !

Comment: @user1929905 xmllint performs an XML parse of the document, giving you more flexibility when processing documents. See my answer below

Answer (score 0):

If gawk is available, you can use a record separator pattern to match XML tags.  The pattern below matches something starting with a <, followed by a character that is not a > one or more times, and terminated by >. When gawk matches an RS, it assigns the matched text to RT.  This gives us a way to match the tags, inspect them, and deal with the values embedded between them.

```
gawk '

  BEGIN { RS="<[^>]+>" }  

  RT == "</Amt>"  { 
    if (previousTag ~ "EUR") { eTotal += $0 }
  } 

  { previousTag = RT; } 

  END { print eTotal }'  myFile
```

For the given sample the above will print out 13.1.  If we want to sum each currency the previousTag could be used as basis for an awk array/hashmap key.